# Trying to get the DI + DI- and ADX values ​at different timeframes 1H, 2H and 4H at the same time in a single time window (pinescript tradingview)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, adx

Someone could help me; I have little experience with pinescript and I am trying to get the DI + DI- and ADX values ​​at different timeframes 1H, 2H and 4H at the same time in a single time window. I found a similar script but it only presents the ADX value of a single temporality in the 4H window and removing the 4H ADX (Eg. 1 hour ADX in the 4 hour window but without the 4H data remaining)

```
`study("Average Directional Index", shorttitle="ADX LP", format=format.price, precision=2, 
resolution="")
adxlen = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing")
dilen = input(14, title="DI Length")
dirmov(len) =>
up = change(high)
down = -change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
truerange = rma(tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / truerange)
minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / truerange)
[plus, minus]

adx(dilen, adxlen) =>
[plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)
sum = plus + minus
adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)

sig = adx(dilen, adxlen)

plot(sig, color=color.red, title="ADX")

> Blockquote`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a built-in function that returns all those three variables called `ta.dmi()`. So, you don't need to do the calculations yourself.

To request data from different time frames, you need to use the `request.security()` function.

So, you need to get the DI+, DI- and ADX values first, then ask for their values in different time frames using the `security()` function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("ADX Multi Timeframe")
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
lensig = input.int(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)

[diplus, diminus, adx] = ta.dmi(len, lensig)
[diplus_1h, diminus_1h, adx_1h] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", [diplus[1], diminus[1], adx[1]], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
[diplus_2h, diminus_2h, adx_2h] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "120", [diplus[1], diminus[1], adx[1]], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
[diplus_4h, diminus_4h, adx_4h] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", [diplus[1], diminus[1], adx[1]], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(adx_1h, color=color.green)
plot(adx_2h, color=color.orange)
plot(adx_4h, color=color.red)
```

[image]